# Android Studio 2.3.3 - Cannot read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

I've already looked at many many other questions but just can't seem to find a solution that would work for me. Note that I also cloned/downloaded the project from GitHub to see how a real application might look like (I was going for a color picker application and was looking for some source code to see an example).

I fixed all the other issues I had but I am stuck with this one issue.

```
Cannot read packageName from F:\Cakedy\Desktop\EVERYTHING\Files\Android Apps\ColorPicker\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Manifest Code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.kuo.colorpicker">

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I am also a beginner FYI in developing applications for android.

Comment: Kindly share the manifest code

Comment: Also, it's better to keep your projects inside folders that don't contain spaces. You have a folder named `Android Apps` so it's better if your folder could be `AndroidApps`

Comment: But is it necessary for my problem? Just asking, would do that soon.

Comment: The manifest code is seems incomplete

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire `AndroidManifest.xml` file. If this is all that you have... then you have quite a few missing pieces.

Comment: Like what missing pieces? Android Studio is really new to me as Visual Studio and Xamarin did this for me I think.

Comment: Manifest code should start and end with `manifest` tag.
e.g: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.package.name">`

Comment: stackoverflow hid the the tags.

Comment: So nothing appears in red in file AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: 3 things do.
https://gyazo.com/63cc8960c477e74a27347d9a04e79a26
The red things cannot be resolved as a symbol apparently.

Comment: So you need to add 3 things. In the `label`, you can put a hardcoded string. For icon, you can find one and put in the mipmap as `ic_launcher` file name and for theme, you have to dig around the internet on how to set themes. Some files seem missing. You cannot run the project unless these errors go away and others if any.

Comment: Ok than. Thanks @NoLuckPulak!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146456/discussion-between-cakedy-and-noluckpulak).

Comment: Yeah... it still doesn't work @NoLuckPulak.